# Ext Ajax request async issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, request

In Ext js, there is a Ext.Ajax.Request to get communicate with server and to get value, but in my application as it is async true, by the time it gets response from server, other code in the js is executing. I tried with async: false, it is impacting other functionality.

Please let me know if there is any other ext class to communicate and get value from server/ any way to handle this scenario.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `async:false` sounds dubious since an Ajax call is inherently asynchronous. However, you need to show us your source code to enable someone to be able to work out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should only use `async: false` if your code is not depending on the returning values.

Since you are using the Ext.Ajax functionality the important question here is:

Are you using the `success` and `failure` callbacks?

If you are waiting for values from the server other code is depending on you should put that code inside the success callback.

The code could look like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
     url: 'ajax_demo/sample.json',

     success: function(response, opts) {
         var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
         console.dir(obj);
     },

     failure: function(response, opts) {
         console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
     }
 });
```

Link to the documentation: [enter link description here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/classic/Ext.Ajax.html)

Comment: I have a success callback

Comment: Can you maybe make a Sencha fiddle (You can use Ext.defer to simulate the asynchronere action)?